# Store date/time of last received REST call in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, node.js-connect

I'm have written an REST API in NodeJs [Connect-rest](https://github.com/imrefazekas/connect-rest) and I was wondering how to go about storing the date and time the last call was made.

### Here is the GET url call

`http://localhost:8080/api/books/metadata?id=12`

### Code snipped that filters this id

```
module.exports.getItem = function(callback, id) {

    var searchLetter = new RegExp(id, 'i');

    //would like to record date/time the last time this call was made to this ID/row
    //return the date/time back in the callback method 
    var row = items.filter(function(itemList) { 
        return searchLetter.test(itemList.asname);
    });

    return callback(null, {items: row, matches: row.length}, {headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'global route' to be used with any api call when your server is setup (that is, if you're using Express or restify or similar):

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log( "Got a request at " + new Date() ); //might want to format date
});
```

(The request parameter might store the time already.)

Some of these frameworks will have an "after" event, that is fired after a request is completely handled (so this logging is not truely part of the chain). Like this example from restify, where I build a custom logging message:

```
server.on( 'after', function logRequest( req, res, route, error ) {

    var latency = res.get( 'Response-Time' );
    if ( typeof( latency ) !== 'number' )
        latency = Date.now() - req._time;

    var obj = {
        userAgent: req.headers[ 'user-agent' ],
        url: req.url,
        method: req.method,
        statusCode: res.statusCode,
        req_id: req.getId()
    };
    obj.latency = latency;
    server.log.info( obj );
} );
```

In this example I am using restify's logging middleware, but you could use your own logger, `console.log`, append to file, etc.

Comment: I'm using Connect-rest, plus I want that for each individual item, which means each individual item might have different time they were accessed!!

Comment: The other framework's `.use()` or `.on('after')` methods are part of the routing chain. So they will get called for each request that goes through the system, each having a different time. (You might require a more fine-grained approach than `new Date()`). I think `connect` will have an option for `app.use()` as well.